# How to deal with errors with FIRMessaging (un)subscribeToTopic?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sometimes when I call `[[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:myTopic]` (or unsubscribe) I see errors logged in the console. Sometimes they have error codes, and other times it's just a message like this:

> Cannot unsubscribe to topic: /topics/my_topic with token: (null)

This one appears to be because it doesn't think it has a token, though usually when I see this I've already given it a token.

There is, however, no apparent programmatic way to know when an error occurred. There's no callback passed to the `subscribe` methods, and their return types are `void`. I think I read somewhere in my Googling of these errors that the library will retry on its own, but I can't find that back now, and it's not in the [documentation for FIRMessaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/interface_f_i_r_messaging.html#aed0f25d909b487b23976b9f3f5076174) anywhere. The error codes are also not documented anywhere that I can find.

One error code I remember seeing specifically is `5`. My implementation used to simplistically re-subscribe / unsubscribe from each topic when the user changed any of them; when I modified this to only update the topic that actually changed, that particular error went away, so maybe it was complaining because I was subscribing to a topic that I was already subscribed to, and vice versa?

How do I deal with these errors? Is it true that the library will retry on its own? And can someone link to an error code listing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to deal with errors that result from subscribe and unsubscribe, it is retried by the SDK automatically. See [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) for more.

Issues with the current error messages is a known, we will improve them in future releases.

Comment: Do you know why subscribing to more than one topic at the same time always fails with `Failed to subscribe to topic Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=5 "(null)"` ? Is it safe to assume these subscription requests will be retried again one by one later? Or auto-retry only works for connection issues?

Comment: Even though `You don't have to deal with errors that result from subscribe and unsubscribe` approach can be good in general, there are some cases where you need the results of these kind of async operations. Sometimes topic names are generated by end-users, and FCM does not accept all topic names (e.g. age65+ because of plus sign).   So, we can not know if it will be retried or not. If you could add an optional error handling, it would be good. Keep up the good work.